# Create object with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to create an object in this format dynamically

```
var query = {"where":{"lang":"en","category":"welcome,common"}};
```

I have these objects

```
console.log(name);
console.log(jsonObj);
```

Console output

```
Array[2]
0: "welcome"
1: "common"



Object
   language: "in" 
   location: "location"
   __proto__: Object
```

I am trying this code..but it is not correct.

```
for(i in name){
    var categoryVal = name[0]+","+name[1]; // this could be more than two..how to loop..??
}
var query = {"where":{"lang": jsonObj.language , "category":categoryVal } };
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `name` is an array, you could use [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```js
var name = ['welcome', 'common'],
  jsonObj = {
    language: "in",
    location: "location"
  };

var query = {
  "where": {
    "lang": jsonObj.language,
    "category": name.join(',')
  }
};

console.log(query)
```

Comment: Thank you Arun P Johny.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go

```js
var arrObj = ["welcome", "common"];
var jsonObj = {
  location:"location",
  language:"in"
  };


function createObj(arrayObj, jsonObj) {
  var newObj = {
    where:{
      category:arrayObj.join(),
      lang: jsonObj.language
      }
    };
  return newObj;
}

var myObj = createObj(arrObj, jsonObj);

console.log(myObj);
```